# Changing Tabs with Selenium WebDriver in Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, xpath

I have li tags in the site and I can't change the tabs, already tried with xpath, currently looks like this:

```
Select objSelect = new Select(objdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='navigation']/li[2]/a")));
WebElement navigation = objdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='navigation']/li[2]/a"));
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div>
<div class="pull-right padding-top">
<a href="http://www.mineotaur.org>">
</div>
<ul id="navigation" class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active">
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#genewise">Gene-wise scatterplot</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#groupwiseDistributionForm">Gene-wise distribution</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#cellwise">Cell-wise scatterplot</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#cellwiseDistribution">Cell-wise distribution</a>
</li>
<li id="toolNav" class="disabled">
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#tools">Tools</a>
</li>
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Share `HTML` code sample for the same and exception log

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass over the driver using this but this is what I use

```
openTabElement.click();
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0));
```